# Как мне узнать разницу во времени?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, datetime

У меня есть дата в базе данных.
`$date = $data['user_date']; //2020-06-22 17:59:43`
Как мне найти разницу между датой сейчас и в базе данных?

Comment: `SELECT DATEDIFF(user_date, NOW())  AS 'DiffDate'  FROM table` Ну, или у вас [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682234/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-php) и вы не умеете пользоваться поиском...

Comment: `strtotime($date)` и `strtotime('now')` <- получите дату в unixtime, если вычесть разницу, то получите кол-во секунд в промежутке межу первой и второй датой. Дальше с помощью элементарной математики можете сконвертировать в минуты/дни/года

Comment: @InDevX Ну вот, а я тут распинаюсь :)